# Nuxt 3.5.1 get error on build " ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sys') (x4) "

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

I have an application made using Nuxt 3.5.1 this is the script tag :

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
     import { IProduct } from './types';
     const p = defineProps<IProduct>();
</script>

types.ts :

export type IProduct =  {
   name?: string;
   id?: number;
   price?: number;
   thumbnail?: string;

   title: string;

}

export interface IProductSecond {
   n: string;
   id: number;
}
```

but when I run

```
>npm run  dev
```

I get this error :
[image]

If I replace :

```
const p = defineProps<IProduct>();
```

with

```
const p = defineProps<{ name?: string;
   id?: number;
   price?: number;
   thumbnail?: string;
   title: string;}>();
```

It works fine

Comment: Can you please add the node version and what package manager are you using? Yarn or npm?

Comment: using npm and Node ver:16.15.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not long since Vue 3.3 is dropped and as of now, Nuxt doesn't have built-in support for Vue 3.3's "Imported Types". There's a workaround for this though:

- If you don't have `typescript` in `package.json`, add it `npm i -D typescript` *(required)*
- Add following code in your `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from "node:fs";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    vue: {
      script: {
        fs: {
          fileExists(file: string) {
            return existsSync(file);
          },
          readFile(file: string) {
            return readFileSync(file, "utf-8");
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

References:

- [Announcing Vue 3.3](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3)
- [Imported types (vue 3.3 feature) not working](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20936) *(Once this issue gets closed, you should remove the workaround)*

Comment: very cool it works like sharm

Answer (score 0):

The config for vite in the nuxt.config.ts isn't necessary anymore. It is enough to install the typescript package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).